# Xarray resample inter annually

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I am trying to resample my data annually, but struggle to set the start day of resampling.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

da = xr.DataArray(
    np.linspace(0, 11, num=36),
    coords=[
        pd.date_range(
            "15/12/1999", periods=36,
        )
    ],
    dims="time",
)
da.resample(time="1Y").mean()
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the means of the following periods: 15/12/1999-15/12/2000, 15/12/2000-15/12/2001, 15/12/2001-15/12/2002, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by shifting the time to the first month and use the corresponding pandas anchored offset. Afterwards, reset the time back.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

da = xr.DataArray(
    np.concatenate([np.zeros(365), np.ones(365)]),
    coords=[
        pd.date_range(
            "06/15/2017", "06/14/2019", freq='D'
        )
    ],
    dims="time",
)

days_to_first_of_month = pd.Timedelta(days=int(da.time.dt.day[0])-1)
da['time'] = da.time - days_to_first_of_month
month = da.time.dt.strftime("%b")[0].values
resampled = da.resample(time=f'AS-{month}').sum()
resampled['time'] = resampled.time + days_to_first_of_month
print(resampled)
```

Is there a more efficient or clean way?